# how to change resource in wpf by code in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Having the next XAML code

```
<Window.Resources >
    <ImageBrush x:Key="tile" ImageSource="afraid.png" 
                Opacity=" 20" TileMode="Tile" 
                ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
                Viewport=" 0,0,32,32"
                ></ImageBrush>
</Window.Resources>
```

I want to change the image by c# code, during the run-time

I have the next code to do this, but the code does not work & I don`t know the reason:

```
        ImageBrush   img = ( ImageBrush )this.FindResource( "tile" );
        ImageSourceConverter conv = new ImageSourceConverter();
        ImageSource  src = ( ImageSource )conv.ConvertFromString( "mad.png" );
        img.ImageSource  = src;
```

Comment: how does it "not work"?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/msbdTzB.png

Comment: is it `img` that is null? Where are you doing `FindResource`?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244893/imagesourceconverter-system-nullreferenceexception).

Try this, create a `BitmapImage` from a file and set it as the `ImageSource` of the ImageBrush.

```
ImageBrush  img = (ImageBrush)this.FindResource("tile");

//change the imagesource in runtime,
img.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("mad.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: i try the cod but nothing happen

Comment: @Default I have found a similar question, see the link in my answer. As it suggested, the Uri path might be wrong so the file is not found, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: more details is required like where the image file is located

Comment: yes, I think you're right! it's the return value from `conv.ConvertFromString` that is null. and yes, I agree with you that more information is required from the OP before a proper answer can be made.